# Loading Bitmap in Image View showing only black colour

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load a JPG in an image view inside a recycler view. But the actual image does not load up instead only black colour is shown in the image view.

```
 try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize=2;
        File file=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS+"/Galanto/RehabRelive/runman1.png");

        final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),options);
        holder.usrImg.setImageBitmap(b);
        b.recycle();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why you're recycling the bitmap?

Comment: Please ignore that. Wrote that line by mistake